# Need excel formula to prescribe which 6 of 8 cells to use for average

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

How can I prescribe which 6 of 8 cells excel uses to make an average?

e.g.:
A1  Art   86
A2  English  88
A3  Law 89
A4  Chemistry 83
A5  Biology 81
A6  Math 1 87
A7  Math 2 67
A8  PhysEd 72

e.g. Average 1 is  A1:A6 / 6
e.g. Average 2 is [top 6 highest] / 6
e.g. Average 3 is Chemistry, English and the next top 4 highest / 6

I  want to define the list where Average 1 = A1:A6/6, Average 2 = ?, Average 3 = ?

Comment: For average 2 you can use the `=LARGE()` function to find the six highest values

Comment: Great. What about Large with exceptions?

Comment: Average 1 and 2 are easy, I'll show you. For average 3, it okay to re-order some of the rows? Namely, to have Chemistry and English at the top of the list, and then the others?

Comment: What do you mean by exceptions? E.g avoid the 5th highest one?

Comment: Exceptions like Average must include Chemistry so count it even if it's lower than top 6 but don't double count it as Chem+Next 5 Largest if Chen is also in top 5.

Comment: Is this for average 2 or average 3?

Comment: Average 2 is good. Thanks. I think Ron's formula will help for 3, and I have to work to define additional averages for more students.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the course descriptions are in column A and the scores are in column B and not Column A

```
B1:B6  =AVERAGE(B1:B6)
Top 6  =AVERAGE(LARGE(B1:B8,{1,2,3,4,5,6}))
```

> Chemistry + English + top 4

```
=(SUM(SUMIF(A1:A8,{"Chemistry","English"},B1:B8))+SUM(LARGE((A1:A8<>"Chemistry")*(A1:A8<>"English")*B1:B8,{1,2,3,4})))/6
```

This last is an array formula and must be entered by holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> while holding down <kbd>Enter</kbd>

A longer formula with the same result, but which can be normally entered:

```
=(SUM(AGGREGATE(14,4,((A1:A8="Chemistry")+(A1:A8="English"))*B1:B8,{1,2}))+SUM(AGGREGATE(14,4,(A1:A8<>"Chemistry")*(A1:A8<>"English")*B1:B8,{1,2,3,4})))/6
```

Answer (score 0):

For #2, You can use Rank() to identify the top 6, then AverageIf() to average those <=6.

For #3, give Chem & English a value of 1, then use Rank() on the remaining 6 items. Then AverageIf() <=4. This is where it helps to put Chem & English at the top of the list.

Here's an example file showing this:
[Click here for the file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bt1t71emfuob3pr/Three%20Averages.xlsx?dl=0)

Anyway, that's ONE way to solve it...  hope it helps!